# Web-сервер для angular

Tags: node.js, nginx, grunt

Доброй ночи! Помогите разгрести всю кашу в голове :)
Разрабатываю проект - документооборот. В целом есть меню, при открытии грузится таблица из базы данных Oracle, добавляются новые данные. В прочем ничего сверхъестественного, основная логика через Oracle (все процедуры, функции).
Проект будет писаться на angular + Rest yii2.
Веб-сервер выбрал nginx. Сколько читаю мануалов, под ангулар предпочтительнее node, только проблема с отдачей файлов. Вот никак не могу решить, стоить ли разделить статику и динамику на nginx+node? Через nginx проксировать динамику на node и кэшировать.
Разрабатываю на отдельной виртуалке, через git заливаю на основной сервак. Для быстроты да и для расширения кругозора решил попробовать Grunt + yeoman. Т.е. у себя локально надо ставить grunt-сервер, на продакшн его не стоит ставить.

Но если брать в расчет проект, где фронт на ангуларе только отрисовка интерфейса(язык, меню), данные (таблица, кол-во рабочих процессов и прочее) из бд. Стоит ли разделять nginx+node? Или оставить все на nginx?

Comment: Чем меньше звеньев и прослоек, всегда лучше.

Answer (score 1):

`angular` и без `node` прекрасно справляется, от только писать неудобно, например, надо подключить какой то `bower component`, то на node это просто одна команда: `bower i component_name`, а чтоб на сервере не закидывать все через `git` - закидываете свои файлы и там просто делаете команду `bower i`. Можно еще сделать так:

1. на локальном компе поставить `node` для удобства в разработке
2. закинуть все файлы на сервере, а там все и так будет работать

Comment: Хорошо, а разница в скорости работы не будет ощутима? Если сравнивать nginx(proxy)-node или один только nginx? Просто через node можно сразу api-oracle использовать, тогда не нужен будет yii2

Comment: Насчет скорости не могу сказать, не пробовал тестировать, но Вам решать на чем программировать. Если node плохо знаете то будет легче на yii2, но как по мне интереснее в чем то новом разобраться)

Comment: Ради этого и хочу изучать, поднять свой скилл :) вот только по срокам успеть бы